Upgrade to Magento 2.4.7 error in module-payment-services-base
After upgrading from Magento 2.4.6 to 2.4.7 I receive the following error, everytime I try to access to payment method configuration (Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Methods):
Exception: Warning: Undefined array key "children" in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-payment-services-base/Plugin/MovePaymentMethods.php on line 66 in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:62
Question:
Any ideas to solve that issue?
Stack trace:
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-payment-services-base/Plugin/MovePaymentMethods.php(44): Magento\PaymentServicesBase\Plugin\MovePaymentMethods->moveMethodToOtherPaymentSolutions(Array, 'express_checkou...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\PaymentServicesBase\Plugin\MovePaymentMethods->afterModify(Object(Magento\Paypal\Model\Config\Structure\PaymentSectionModifier\Interceptor), Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Paypal\Model\Config\Structure\PaymentSectionModifier\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/Config/Structure/PaymentSectionModifier/Interceptor.php(22): Magento\Paypal\Model\Config\Structure\PaymentSectionModifier\Interceptor->___callPlugins('modify', Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Config/StructurePlugin.php(143): Magento\Paypal\Model\Config\Structure\PaymentSectionModifier\Interceptor->modify(Array)
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Config/StructurePlugin.php(119): Magento\Paypal\Model\Config\StructurePlugin->restructurePayments(Object(Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Section))
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Paypal\Model\Config\StructurePlugin->aroundGetElementByPathParts(Object(Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Array)


I’ll take a look tomorrow

If you have any third party extension of payment method, then try to disable it and then check.

it was a vanilla installation. I could fix that with disabling all paypal modules. But I would like to find a more easy way.

The plugin MovePaymentMethods is not enabled by anything in a vanilla install as far as I see it. In this case, 1. you should be able to disable this plugin. 2. it seems something else enables the plugin and that may be a third-party module indeed

strange ok I have some third-party modules but all of them are not related to MovePaymentMethods. I will investigate.

ok, now I deactivated all third-party modules and enabled all native module, but as a result the error still exists.

hi Martin , did you find any solution, I am facing same issue after upgrade to 2.4.7

What worked for me, was deactivating PayPal completely:
php /bin/magento module:disable Magento_ReCaptchaPaypal   Magento_PaymentServicesSaaSExport Magento_PaymentServicesDashboard Magento_PaymentServicesBase Magento_PaymentServicesPaypal Magento_PaypalGraphQl Magento_Paypal   Magento_PaymentServicesPaypalGraphQl Magento_PaypalCaptcha PayPal_Braintree PayPal_BraintreeCustomerBalance   PayPal_BraintreeGiftCardAccount PayPal_BraintreeGiftWrapping     PayPal_BraintreeGraphQl --clear-static-content'

but what if we use the paypal as payment method ?

Any updates on this one?
To me 2.4.7 update was full of this types of surprises. It was like they didn't even test before releasing.

Until now I can't find another way

The solution above did not work for me, is there another solution?

the modified MovePaymentMethods.php below is working for me as well.

Updated File :
vendor/magento/module-payment-services-base/Plugin/MovePaymentMethods.php
<?php

/************************************************************************
 *
 * Copyright 2014 Adobe
 * All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * NOTICE: All information contained herein is, and remains
 * the property of Adobe and its suppliers, if any. The intellectual
 * and technical concepts contained herein are proprietary to Adobe
 * and its suppliers and are protected by all applicable intellectual
 * property laws, including trade secret and copyright laws.
 * Dissemination of this information or reproduction of this material
 * is strictly forbidden unless prior written permission is obtained
 * from Adobe.
 * ************************************************************************
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Magento\PaymentServicesBase\Plugin;

use Magento\Paypal\Model\Config\Structure\PaymentSectionModifier;

class MovePaymentMethods
{
    private const RECOMMENDED_SOLUTIONS = 'recommended_solutions';
    private const CHILDREN = 'children';
    private const RECOMMENDED_SOLUTIONS_ALLOWED_LIST = ['magento_payments_legacy', 'magento_payments'];
    private const OTHER_PAYPAL_PAYMENT_SOLUTIONS = 'other_paypal_payment_solutions';

    /**
     * Move payment methods not allowed to other_paypal_payment_solutions
     *
     * @param PaymentSectionModifier $subject
     * @param array $result
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */

    public function afterModify(PaymentSectionModifier $subject, $result)
    {
        if (isset($result[self::RECOMMENDED_SOLUTIONS][self::CHILDREN])) {
            foreach (array_keys($result[self::RECOMMENDED_SOLUTIONS][self::CHILDREN]) as $key) {
                if (!in_array($key, self::RECOMMENDED_SOLUTIONS_ALLOWED_LIST, true)) {
                    $result = $this->moveMethodToOtherPaymentSolutions($result, $key);
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Move other payment method by key to other_paypal_payment_solutions
     *
     * @param array $result
     * @param int|string $key
     * @return array
     */
    public function moveMethodToOtherPaymentSolutions(array $result, int|string $key): array
    {
        if (isset($result[self::RECOMMENDED_SOLUTIONS][self::CHILDREN][$key])) {
            if (!isset($result[self::OTHER_PAYPAL_PAYMENT_SOLUTIONS][self::CHILDREN])) {
                $result[self::OTHER_PAYPAL_PAYMENT_SOLUTIONS][self::CHILDREN] = [];
            }

$result[self::OTHER_PAYPAL_PAYMENT_SOLUTIONS][self::CHILDREN] =
    array_merge(
        [
            $result[self::RECOMMENDED_SOLUTIONS][self::CHILDREN][$key]
        ],
        $result[self::OTHER_PAYPAL_PAYMENT_SOLUTIONS][self::CHILDREN]
    );

unset($result[self::RECOMMENDED_SOLUTIONS][self::CHILDREN][$key]);
}
return $result;
}
}


Any ideas why this is happening? I have 5 websites with each having 1 store view but only one website/store is having this issue.

the problem seems to be the "new Adobe payment" plugin. The solution above "MovePaymentMethods.php" works but strangely on one server the problem did not occur after upgrade to 2.4.7

As a workaround, you can disable the plugin from a custom module.
etc/adminhtml/di.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Paypal\Model\Config\Structure\PaymentSectionModifier">
        <plugin name="move_express_checkout_us_to_other_paypal_payment_solutions" disabled="true"/>
    </type>
</config>

